# Android Tabbed Activity - pass spinner value from nested fragment, to tab fragment in parent activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

That's a mouthful. I have a basic Tabbed Activity with two tabs, each tab shares a fragment with a spinner, which is declared in each tab's layout file:

Tab 1:

```
<fragment android:name="com.me.fragment.DetailsFragment"
          android:id="@+id/DetailsFragment1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Tab 2:

```
<fragment android:name="com.me.fragment.DetailsFragment"
          android:id="@+id/DetailsFragment2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The main Tabbed Activity class, of course, has two nested static Fragment classes; one for each tab.

```
public class MyTabbedActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    public static class FirstTabFragment extends Fragment
    {
        //get value from DetailsFragment and "refresh" display values
    }

    public static class SecondTabFragment extends Fragment
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass the selected value of the spinner in the nested DetailsFragment above, to the nested static tab classes in the tabbed activity, so data can be filtered therein.

That is to say...when the activity is first loaded, a default set of data is called and displayed in the tab(s). When the spinner selection changes in DetailsFragment, a parameter is passed to the tab class and the data is filtered, and values displayed are changed.

I'm able to pass the a value from DetailsFragment to the main activity (MyTabbedActivity) with an interface, but am unsure how to pass that value to the nested FirstTabFragment and SecondTabFragment fragments, and refresh/reload the view.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using libraries, I would highly recommend [Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Then in your Details fragment you just do

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(value);
```

And in the fragment you want to receive the value add

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

to the onCreate and make a method called

```
public void onEvent(ValueType value){
    // do what you want with the value here
}
```

That will take your value and post it to anything that matches that value type (i.e if your value is a String, any onEvent method taking in a string as a parameter will receive the value). Due to this, it is recommended to create an event class to pass instead.

```
public class DetailFragmentEvent{
    private String value;

    public DetailFragmentEvent(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return value
    }
}
```

and then pass that in your post. That way you can keep your events separate. You can use event bus with pretty much any object you want and it is much simpler than writing a ton of interfaces.

Also, in any class you register the event bus, unregister it on destroy.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

Comment: @Zameron - I'd prefer to avoid any extra libraries, if possible. Is this what's required then? Another interface listener to pass the value from the main activity to the tab fragment classes?

Comment: Do all the fragments exist at the same time, or are you starting the fragments after getting the value from the detail fragment?

Comment: All fragments exist at all times, none are being swapped or changed based on the changing parameters. I'm using the spinner on top to filter the data inside the tab fragments, is all.